Minimum Width Setting Not Available in Power Apps
I am trying to create an app in power app through watching video tutorial and I came across with one that needs to modify the minimum width setting of a vertical screen container. When I check the settings, it is not available on my end? Is there any way that I can have it on my power app as well? Or are there any settings that I need to change on my power app?

